# Can't stop at exception in IntelliJ IDEA while writing Kotlin code

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin

My code is trowing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in a JUnit 4.12 test, I want to stop at that exception when it is thrown, but I can't for some reason.

Here are my debugger settings:

[image: Debugger settings]

When I run my code with *Debug*, the exception is just logged to the console, and the debugger won't stop at the line where it has occurred.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added any 'Class Filters' to 'Any Exception' Breakpoint?

Comment: @NataliaUkhorskaya Nope, I tried fiddling with it, but to no success. This behavior happens with this exact setup that is displayed on the screenshot.

Comment: @NataliaUkhorskaya Is this a bug, should I report it?

Comment: I've missed that you unchecked 'Uncaught exception' checkbox. No, it's not a bug. If you run tests all exceptions become 'caught exceptions' because of JUnit infrastructure. The same way breakpoints in Java Code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way to stop at exception in a JUnit test is to create an exception breakpoint rule for that exception, because JUnit catches any excepiton that occurred in a test. Here is what I did:

[image: New configuration]